# angular-cli webpack how to serve generate dist folder on express server

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am using angular 4 with angular-cli so I stuck at a point where I have
generated dist folder using ng build --prod which I have to serve on express server.
I have existing setup where I am running angular 1 code.

Comment: Is this "some other url" is in completely different domain?

Comment: domain is same exploring https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-proxy this url for solving issue

Comment: Just tell me how to use express server in Angular cli I have full setup in Angular 1.x where I am using gulp

Comment: You can't use express server in Angular cli as far as I know. But you can build and put your angular project bundles inside express project.

Comment: Did you try **routerLink** to redirect ? are you using angular router, it is not clear from your question that what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: yes i am using router = require('express').Router()  now i am able to serve other url like reset and register on sso url only problem now i am facing is to serve complied dist folder generated using ng build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the gist of it

In your express application, define the routes.For example if you need two routes,

1. For serving client side(in this case Angular)
2. Other for REST APIs

Then in your server.js you will have following routes.

```js
    //assuming you have configured your express configuration in server.js
    var express = require('express');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var path = require('path');
    var app = express();
    var http = require('http').Server(app);
    var index = require('./routes/index');
    var apis = require('./routes/apis')(http);
    ......
    // I am skipping codes which are common
    //add the routes 
    //Pointing to Index file of routes
    app.use('/', index);
    //apis - Pointing to apis file of routes
    app.use('/api', apis);
```

Then in routes folder let's define index.js file and in that let us define route for serving client.

```js
// /routes/index.js
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    router.get('', function (req, res, next) { 
        res.render('index.html');
    });
    module.exports = router;
```

Now in views folder let's assume that we have index.html file. In this file I am importing compiled main.js file of Angular 4

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sample App</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <base href="/">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylsheet" href ="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="src/systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('src/main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- This is the main angular component selector tag-->
    <my-app>Loading.....</my-app>
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  
</ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please observe that I am using systemjs.

**Important!** Change the path to **main.js** according. For example, try building angular project into **src** folder.Below is the snippet of tsconfig.json file of Angular 4

```js
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src", // the compiled code will go to src folder
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

If you use **ng serve**, this command will wipe out built files in src directory in this case. So use **ng build --watch** to build and watch your changes

For expressjs to observe changes, install nodemon and type command **nodemon** to run application.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: with your script when I run command node server.js nothing happens while i used mine main.js which is having code to run express it starts express but there problem is I hit localhost:5002
it loads index.html showing as Loading...
When I go to browser debugger to see the source files in each file it has code which is in index.html hence angular app does not work.
e.g. main.js having so where is the actual code gone

Comment: When I am running dist folder using nginx server it runs index.html properly only thing is I have to set proxies but with express it is not loading supporting js file properly

Comment: The above mentioned way is one way to do it. Follow https://scotch.io/tutorials/mean-app-with-angular-2-and-the-angular-cli post to get it working properly. Of course there is another way to run the projects separately one express project and other angular project. And as you mentioned you need to use proxies.